# Finding the angle between two lines in the complex plane without converting to real and imaginary components

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, angle

How do you find the angle between two lines in the complex plane, without going through the real route (breaking $z$ into $x+yi$ and solving by finding the tangent from the slopes)?

For example, if my lines were in the form

$$\begin{align}
az+\overline{az} + b &=0 \\
dz+\overline{dz} + c &=0 \\
\end{align}$$

for complex $a$, $d$ and real $b$, $c$.

I know we can determine if they are parallel or perpendicular by multiplying $ad$ and seeing if it is zero, or if $d$ is a scalar of $a$, but does this help? Would this in any way involve finding the arccos() between two vectors?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks~

Comment: Hint: $az+\overline{az} + b=0 \iff \text{Re}(az) = -b/2$ means that $\,az\,$ lies on a line parallel to the imaginary axis.

Comment: @dxiv Indeed this form of the complex expression of a line is very handy and deserves to be better known !

Answer (score 2):

Switch your notation to polar and express your lines as vectors with angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. Angle in between is simply their difference, so $\Delta \theta$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This seems to be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote
$$
 L_1 = \{ z \in \Bbb C \mid az+\overline{az} + b=0 \} \, ,\\
 L_2 = \{ z \in \Bbb C \mid dz+\overline{dz} + c=0 \} \, .
$$
with $a, d \in \Bbb C\setminus \{ 0 \}$ and $b, c\in \Bbb R$. Since
$$
 az+\overline{az} + b = d\left( \frac ad z+\frac{b-c}{2d}\right)
+ \overline {d\left( \frac ad z+\frac{b-c}{2d}\right)} + c
$$
we have
$$
 z \in L_1 \iff  \frac ad z+\frac{b-c}{2d} \in L_2 \, .
$$

If $a/d$ is not a real number then the two lines intersect at a single point and the oriented angle from $L_1$ to $L_2$ is $\arg(a/d)$.

Otherwise the lines are identical ($b=c$) or parallel ($b \ne c$).

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler, WLOG, to work at the origin, bringing by translation the equations of the lines to be:

$$az+\overline{az}=0, \ \ dz+\overline{dz}=0   $$

otherwise said, as @dxiv has recalled it:

$$\Re(az)=0, \ \ \Re(dz')=0   \tag{1}$$

where we can assume, WLOG again, that $|a|=|d|=|z|=|z'|=1$ (where $z$ and $z'$ are now considered as representative points of their resp. lines at distance $1$ from the origin).

With evident notations, (1) becomes:

$$\Re(e^{i \alpha}e^{i\theta})=0, \ \ \Re(e^{i \delta}e^{i\theta'})=0$$

$$\cos(\alpha+\theta)=0, \ \ \ \ \cos(\delta+\theta')=0$$

$$\alpha+\theta=\pi/2 + k \pi,  \ \ \ \ \delta+\theta'=\pi/2 + k' \pi \tag{2}$$

Therefore, by subtracting the relationships in (2), we obtain the angular "gap" between the two lines:

$$\theta'-\theta = \underbrace{ \alpha - \delta}_{arg(\tfrac{a}{d})} + k'' \pi$$